# Update using a group by

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I need to update one table using group by on a particular attribute and then updating the same table.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve

Sample records:

Table ABC

```
KEY REF_NO ATT_KEY
1   200    1
2   200    2
3   200    3
4   283    4
5   283    5
6   283    6
7   400    8
8   400    11
```

The output that i would like to see: Group by ref number and with in the group if i find that atleast one of the att_key is odd number then i have to flip all the even number to even_number - 1 and odd numbers will remain the same. set of numbers for att_key (1,2,3...24)

Table ABC Output:

```
KEY REF_NO ATT_KEY
1   200    1
2   200    1
3   200    3
4   283    3
5   283    5
6   283    5
7   400    7
8   400    11
```

I have difficulty in getting this logic. Looking for help/suggestions

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using window functions.  This approach uses the `max()` of the remainder:

```
select key, ref_no,
       (case when max(mod(att_key, 2)) over (partition by ref_no) = 1 and
                  mod(att_key, 2) = 0
             then att_key - 1
             else att_key
        end) as newkey
from table t;
```

I'm not sure where the condition on `ATT_KEY` being between 1 and 24 fits in.  Perhaps you also need a `WHERE` clause.

You can also phrase this as an update:

```
update t
    set att_key = att_key - 1
    where mod(att_key, 2) = 0 and
          exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t.ref_no = t2.ref_no and mod(att_key, 2) = 1
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca208/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC ( KEY, REF_NO, ATT_KEY ) AS
          SELECT 1,   200,    1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,   200,    2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3,   200,    3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4,   283,    4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5,   283,    5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6,   283,    6 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 7,   400,    8 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 8,   400,    11 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 9,   500,    12 FROM DUAL;

UPDATE ABC a
SET    ATT_KEY = ATT_KEY - 1
WHERE  MOD( ATT_KEY, 2 ) = 0
AND    EXISTS (
  SELECT 'X'
  FROM   ABC b
  WHERE  MOD( ATT_KEY, 2 ) = 1
  AND    a.REF_NO = b.REF_NO
);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ABC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca208/1/0)**:

```
| KEY | REF_NO | ATT_KEY |
|-----|--------|---------|
|   1 |    200 |       1 |
|   2 |    200 |       1 |
|   3 |    200 |       3 |
|   4 |    283 |       3 |
|   5 |    283 |       5 |
|   6 |    283 |       5 |
|   7 |    400 |       7 |
|   8 |    400 |      11 |
|   9 |    500 |      12 |
```

Comment: Awesome. This logic should work. Let me try. My table has a lot of rows. Probably i may have to convert this to merge.

Comment: If this has answered you question you can mark it as accepted to close the question (and upvote this or any other answers you think are valuable).